# Scala Extract the column from struct

Tags: mysql, scala, struct

I want to make a query `df.select()` and extract the `created_at` field from the struct below in Scala. I have tried various different techniques such as explode and flattening but that is not what I want. I am unable to understand how I can parse the tree to get the `created_at` from a nested struct. Here is the schema

Comment: Did you try `df.select($"user.created_at")`?

Comment: Yeah. I did. Since I'm getting multiple columns (df.select( "name", "id_str", $"user.created_at", ); I keep getting an error (attached image)

Comment: You shouldn't mix `String`-type column names with `Column`s in `select()`.  Try `df.select($"name", $"id_str", $"user.created_at")` instead.

Comment: Got it! It's working now. Thanks